# How do Swift allocates in memory value-type that conforms to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, value-type

I was thinking of how do Swift **allocates in memory value-type objects** like structs, enums etc that conforms to some protocol. Like I always thought - types that conforms to some protocol should have **same size** of allocated memory in way to **generalise** all possible types that will be conformed to protocol. Such like reference-like values stored in memory like one reference to generalise objects by protocols or by custom class hierarchy. And I think value-types objects should allocates the same way to **generalise all protocol-conformed value-types**. Because of each one of protocol-conformed structs, enums... would have a **different size of needed memory**.

Hope someone can explain me that moment, thanks!

Comment: Conforming to a protocol does not tell you anything about the memory layout of an object, be it a value type object or a reference type object. Protocol conformance tells you that conforming objects will implement certain methods and include certain properties. You could draw some conclusions about the minimum storage that would be needed for the stored properties declared in the protocol, but that's it. Any object that conforms to a given protocol can also have additional stored properties, it can store those properties in an arbitrary order, etc.

Comment: You have very cleverly reinvented existential containers and witness tables, which is exactly what Swift uses to solve the problem you've discovered. It's possible to answer here, but a better resource would be straight from the Swift team where they explain this. The best resources is from WWDC 2016: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/416/. This was then expanded on in WWDC 2018: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/406/ (Would it be better if this were in the Swift docs rather than WWDC videos. Yes, yes it would.)

Comment: @Duncan C But how then will stored in memory for example *function parameter of protocol type*? I mean compilator should allocate same memory for function parameter (because we are talking about type-dependent compiled language) be it a value-type or a reference-type.

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you so much! Now I know the source of such educational material! You helped me a lot :)